# Increment Numbers When Value Changes

Tags: worksheet-function

Is there a way to change the value once the value of another column has changed?

Below is what I want so all APPLE are tagged 1, Pear 2 and ORANGE 3 (working with many different values so can't be IF APPLE = 1 etc):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX/MATCH with relative range:

```
=IF(A2<>"",IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B1,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A1,0)),MAX($B$1:$B1)+1),"")
```

This will try to find a match and if not found it will place the next number in order.  If found it will use the number it finds.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I want to drag this down the bottom of the sheet so I can continue to add info in Column A - Currently,  this formula will continue counting blanks.

Comment: @Phil see edit.